# text-overflow com quebra de linha

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando usar a propriedade text-overflow para usar reticencias mas também queria usar quebra de linha na primeira linha.

Preciso que a tenha uma quebra de linha na primeira linha e na segunda usar reticencias. Algo parecido com:

```
quebra de texto 
quebra de ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tmk3546b/3/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

> [...] Você pode fazer isso usando o 
>   `-webkit-box` e `-webkit-line-clamp`-
>   Exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/ArKeu/7/

Link da solução original em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004006/is-vertical-text-overflow-possible-with-css3

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma solução em JavScript que achei mais simples e que funcionou no meu caso porque com CSS não tava funcionando. Basicamente eu fiz assim:

1. Criei um elemento HTML

   const figcaption = document.createElement('figcaption')
2. No texto inseri a string

   const bio = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
3. Limitei em 55 caracteres, removi espaços e concatenei as reticências

   figcaption.innerHTML = bio.substr(0, 55).trim().concat('...');
4. Adicionei o 'figcaption' na figure

   figure.appendChild(figcaption);

```js
const figure = document.querySelector('.figure');
const figcaption = document.createElement('figcaption');
const bio = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
figcaption.innerHTML = bio.substr(0, 55).trim().concat('...');
figure.appendChild(figcaption);
```

```html
<figure class="figure"></figure>
```